# Firebase Analytics Event about notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I am using FCM.

I made app server and send notification through app server.

I followed document of firebase analytic. Now, i want to know notification_open and notification_dismiss.

But it only show me notification_foreground and notification_receive.

According to https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en,

Notification_open and notification_dismiss is automatically collected event.

Why i can't get notification_dismiss and notification_open event?

---

Following image is my all analytics event on console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPt2e.png)

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation for the notification events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) all contain the phrase "when sent by Firebase Notifications".

For example: ***notification_receive*** -- when a notification sent by Firebase Notifications is received by a device when the app is in the background

My experience is that "sent by Firebase Notifications" means "sent from the Notification panel of the Firebase Console". The events are not generated when the notifications are created by posting data to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`.

Comment: Thank your answer. Do you know how can i get data about notification_open?